# Use Angular 9 DomSanitizer to run inline scripts with innerHtml

Tags: angular

Have a file containing html, css and script.

```html
<style>
  h1{
    color: darkgreen;
  }
</style>

<H1 id="header">Title</H1>

<script>
  alert("script executed");
</script>
```

I am using angular Domsanatizer, the html and css works, but the script is not executed.

In Component .ts file

```
this.safeContentFromFile = this.sanatizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.contentFromFile);
```

Component template

```html
<div *ngIf="contentReady" [innerHtml]="safeContentFromFile" id="content-window"></div>
```

Any suggestion on how to get the script to work with this.

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a non-starter as the Html5 spec specifically forbids scripts to execute if it was inserted using innerHtml. My guess therefore is that this is not even an Angular limitation. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that angular was preventing the javascript from executing. I used a iframe to do what I wanted to do.